# Calculating a hash value for composite classes

Tags: c++, hash

I have a class structure like the following:

```
class A
{
    int x,y,z;
    int w[4];
};

bool operator==(const A& a1, const A& a2) 
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        if (a1.w[i] != a2.w[i])
            return false;
    return (a1.x == a2.x && a1.y == a2.y && a1.z == a2.z)
}

class B
{
    int q,p;
    vector<A> a;
};

bool operator==(const B& b1, const B& b2) 
{ 
    return (b1.q == b2.q && b1.a == b2.a)
}
```

Now I need custom hash value for class B, for which it is important that member p is **not** relevant, i.e. two instances with equal values (including all instances of A in the vector a) except for p should have the same hash. For the hash value of class A all members are relevant.

I looked up suited functions and came across DJBHash:

```
unsigned int DJBHash(const char* str, unsigned int length)
{
   unsigned int hash = 5381;
   unsigned int i    = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < length; ++str, ++i)
   {
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + (*str);
   }

   return hash;
}
```

I now have two questions:

1. The input for this function is a string equivalent. Is there a performant way to turn my integer members into suited input? My approach would be hand crafting the hash function by entering the values manually, but I assume there could be some trick like having all the member variables behind each other in memory, etc.
2. Would the hash value of B consist of all the hash values of instances of A in the vector a? Or does this hierarchical calculation result in errors?

I'd very much appreciate any advise on this.

Comment: The `DJBHash` function is essentially working with an array of bytes. You can do something similar for you integer based class. Do you want your hash value to change based on the values stored in `a`? Are all fields of the `A` objects important for the hash computation? [Edit] the question to include these details. Also, add the `operator==` for `class B` if you have one, since the hash for two equivalent objects should be the same.

Comment: Yes, all values in `a` are relevant for `class B` and all members of `class A` are relevant for it. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a performant way to turn my integer members into suited input

First, let's try something naive and readable, and see if it's good enough.

Here is an incremental version of the algorithm:

```cpp
struct Djb2Hash {
  unsigned int hash = 5381;
  
  void Add(char c) {
    hash = hash * 33 + c;
  }
};
```

Then add some more higher-order functions to compose the struct:

```cpp
struct Djb2Hash {
    /* ... */

    void Add(int value) {
        char bytes[sizeof(int)];
        memcpy(bytes, &value, sizeof(int));
        for (auto c : bytes) {
            Add(c);
        }
    }

    void Add(const A& value) {
        Add(value.x);
        Add(value.y);
        Add(value.z);
        for (auto w : value.w) {
            Add(w);
        }
    }

    void Add(const B& value) {
        Add(value.q);
        for (auto& a : value.a) {
            Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

...And turn on your compiler's optimizer:

https://godbolt.org/z/rceGcc

The compiler:

- Figured out `hash*33` is a shift and an add
- Skipped the `memcpy` and read the bytes directly
- Read the bytes in integer-size blocks
- Inlined most of the methods
- Unrolled all the loops except the `std::vector` of A's.

That's *pretty darn good*. You might squeeze more performance out by finding a SIMD implementation of the algorithm, aligning your structs, putting the non-hashed values last, making sure your compiler contiguously packs your structs on each platform you're supporting, and hashing a block of underlying bytes.

But then your code will be less readable, more complicated, and then you're depending on implementation-defined behavior. So if the performance here is not a bottleneck, I'd say stick with the naive way.